# Why do i get Black Screen when navigating status on WhatsApp Web?

Tags: google-chrome, heap-memory, whatsapp

It occurs sometimes that when viewing and navigating through the **next** or **prev** button, I get a blank screen [[Screenshot here](https://ibb.co/fkKXZM8)] which I have to refresh the page to use WhatsApp web again and now it happens all the time.

Why is this happening? Could Chrome memory heap be the reason for this?

I make use of 12GB memory and my [CPU & RAM usage screenshot](https://ibb.co/w4JKMXy).

Answer (score 0):

I hope This will be solution. Try it once.
Try clearing your browser cache and cookies, or try using WhatsApp Web on a different browser to see if the issue persists. If the problem continues, you could try resetting Chrome to its default settings.
I have experienced it in past let me know if it works.

Comment: Clearing cache and cookie doesn't work, but rather deleting the chrome user data does work temporarily.